# How to setup Kubernetes HPA to scale based on maximum available memory in a given pod?

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

I’d like to autoscale the pods not based on the average memory, but rather based on largest amount of available memory in a given pod.

Example:

Let’s say the target maximum available memory is 50%.

If we have 7 pods already and 6 of them have 90% occupied memory, but a single pod with 40% occupied memory, that’d satisfy my criteria and we won’t need to upscale. But the moment that last pod goes below 50% available memory we’ll upscale.

I know it’s not a wise criteria for scaling in case majority of case, but in my particular circumstance, it fits.

Comment: Have you searched already? Kubernetes allows for custom metrics based HPA, which might be helpful here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#scaling-on-custom-metrics

Comment: Yes, my understanding was that these metrics come out of individual pods but the final aggregation of values is done by k8 and it’s always an average. I might be wrong